# Django, 1.9.10 Language matching query does not exist

Tags: python, linux, django

I am a struggling beginner and I will appreciate your help.
I have cloned a Django site to edit and learn from it but I can not runserver.
On running server I get the error 
Language matching query does not exist.

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/software/features
Django Version: 1.9.10
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
Language matching query does not exist.
Exception Location: /home/steve/Documents/wger/venv-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in get, line 387
Python Executable:  /home/steve/Documents/wger/venv-django/bin/python
Python Version: 3.5.2
Python Path:    
['/home/steve/Documents/wger/wger-croners',
 '/usr/lib/python35.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/home/steve/Documents/wger/venv-django/lib/python3.5/site-packages',
 '/home/steve/.config/wger']
Server time:    Mon, 24 Oct 2016 19:48:24 +0300
/home/steve/Documents/wger/wger-croners/wger/utils/language.py in load_language
    language = Language.objects.get(short_name=used_language)
```

What could be wrong? I have followed all instructions on the Git readme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because there is no entry in `Language` model where `short_name` equals to `used_language`. For details, read: [Retrieve Object from Django Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-objects)

In case you want to create object with `short_hand` as`used_language` in case not found, use [`.get_or_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) instead as:

```
 language, is_created = Language.objects.get_or_create(short_name=used_language)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @anonymous let me try that and get back to you. I appreciate.

Comment: Thanks @anonymous it worked! I hope i will gain genius thinking like you some day! thanks!